# Multivariable Taylor and partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Any idea how to prove this? I know it's Taylor related, and the Taylor expansion of $(u^3-v)$ it's $(u^3-v)$ because it's a polynomial. But I don't how what to do with the sin...

> Let $f(u,v)=(u^3-v)\cdot\sin(u+v) \Longrightarrow \dfrac{\partial^n f}{\partial u^j \partial v^{n-j}}(0,0)=0 \;\; \; \forall \; n\in \mathbb{N} \; \;\text{odd}.$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is an even function, so all the terms of odd degree in its Taylor expansion vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Start expanding
$$\left(u^3-v\right) \sin (u+v)=$$ $$u^3 \sin (u) \cos (v)+u^3 \cos (u) \sin (v)-v \sin (u) \cos (v)-v \cos (u) \sin(v)$$Now use the series around $u=0$ and $v=0$.

This is Taylor expansion for multiple variables.